# How to use bootstrap with react without using any extra css file and how to apply the classnames?

Tags: reactjs

How to use bootstrap with react without using any extra  css file and how to apply the classnames ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-bootstrap which has its own way of setting styles:

```
Link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/
```

In case u want to use general bootstrap:

Create a React app:

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

now u can directly add uer bootstrap dependencies in uer `public/index.html` page (CDN URL), or u can install uer bootstrap dependencies using `npm`

```
cd my-app
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

Once you have installed all the dependencies, include then your `src/index.js` entry file. Also, now u can use the bootstrap classes using `className` attribute in react components as shown below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

const app = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <h3>Column 1</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad..</p>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <h3>Column 2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
                    <p>Ut enim ad..</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```